# Does this system have a finite, an infinite or no solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Here is a system of linear equations:

$$x_1+x_2=20$$
$$x_2+x_3=20$$
$$-x_1+x_5=10$$
$$x_3-x_4=-20$$
$$x_4-x_5=10$$

I managed to express each variable in terms of $x_1$.
$$x_1=x_1$$
$$x_2=-x_1+20$$
$$x_3=x_1$$
$$x_4=x_1+20$$
$$x_5=x_1+10$$

But I can't seem to find the value of any one variable.

I did try choosing random values for $x_1$ and finding the other values from that. I tested it for $x_1=0$ and $x_1=10$. The 2 sets obtained satisfied the system of equations. It seems that there are multiple or infinite solutions to this system.

But I have 5 equations with 5 unknowns. Shouldn't I be able to solve that?
How do I show/prove the number of solutions to this system of equations?

Comment: You've shown that every variable depends on $x_1$ in a solution, so there's a solution corresponding to every real value of $x_1$ i.e. there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Oh so expressing each variable in terms of one of the variables was the right approach? Great, thanks

Comment: Yes it was, basically because you can use it show that there are infinitely many solutions. There's a solution for $x_1=0$ and for $x_1=1$ and $x_1=2$ and so on (these are all different because $x_1$'s value is different in each of them), so you get infinitely many different solutions that way, giving you the answer to your question.

Comment: I can't see any $x_1$ in your initial system. Is there a typo?

Comment: @F.Carette I made a number of typos, thanks.

Comment: "But I have 5 equations with 5 unknowns." Not really. Since one of your 5 initial equations is redudant (e.g. the last one), you actually only have 4 (compatible) equations, which leaves you one "degree of freedom" (e.g. the choice of $x_1$), whence infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @AnneBauval Why us the last equation redundant? Sorry , I can't see why.

Comment: Because $$(x_1+x_2=20,x_2+x_3=20,-x_1+x_5=10,x_3-x_4=-20)\iff$$ $$(x_2=-x_1+20,x_3=x_1,x_4=x_1+20,x_5=x_1+10)$$ $$\implies x_4-x_5=10.$$

Comment: "But I have 5 equations with 5 unknowns. Shouldn't I be able to solve that?"  !!!IF!!! the 5 equations are linearly independent.  Which these are not.   One of your equations can be derived from the the others.  Consider this $a + b = 5$ and $-2a -2b =-10$.  That's two eqations and two unknown but the second equation is just the same of the first equation with everything multiplied by $-2$.  Or $a+b=5; b+c=4; a-c=1$.  Here the third equation is just the first minus the second.  You've got something similar (just not so obvious)

Comment: @AnneBauval  Unless, I'm mistaken we can declare any of the equations redundant, couldn't we?

Comment: ... and to beat a dead horse:   Technically, we can say 1) $x + y = 7$ and 2) $x+y=7$ is also two equations and two unknowns.  It's just that it is two of the *same* equations.